# How to find dimension of a device in DPs via ADB

Tags: android, adb, dumpsys

I got dimensions of a device using -

```
adb shell wm size
```

other ways to get it, -

```
adb shell dumpsys display | grep mBaseDisplayInfo
```

But I am not able to find device's resolution in DPs. (which should be 360x480)

In android code , we can do it using -

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics(); 
float screenWidthDp = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
```

Now here I have width in Pixels from ADB, but can't get this `density` using `ADB`. There is a method to get density through `ADB` -

```
adb shell wm density
```

but that give results such as `480` `420`, so it is different density than the one we got by `displayMetrics.density` (which is a single digit number ie 2, 3 or  2.65).

Any idea how can I get device's dimensions in DPs or `displayMetrics.density` using ADB?

Comment: Finally I ended up using app instead of doing it through ADB.

Comment: Did you find the proper adb command for this?  I am wondering the same

Comment: No, I couldn't. I then created an app using above mentioned API and did some manual steps :/